# Dynamicaly change IE version using Watin

Tags: internet-explorer, version, automated-tests, watin

I am using IE9 and I have made a web test project using Watin.
But some pages I want to open using IE8 (lower version) instead of IE9

My sample code:

```
Browser browserInstance;
browserInstance = new IE(@"http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start your IE specific version and the attach to it.

```
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
            IE browser = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(p=>p.StartsWith("https://www.google.com"))); // assuming your start web page is google.com
            browser.GoTo("http://www.yahoo.com");
```